# Inclusion–exclusion principle problem - distributing sweets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

What is the number of all possible ways of distributing 16 DIFFERENT candies
in a group consisting of 2 male and 4 female students if each male student receives at most 3
sweets?

I have no idea how to use this principle in this case.
When I did a similar task in which the condition was that each boy gets at least one candy it was easy but I don't know how to do it for "at most 3"

Comment: Please **edit the question** to tell us what you've tried and where you're having trouble.  Questions that show no evidence of independent effort to reach a solution usually are not well received here.

Comment: Figure out how many distributions put at least $4$ candies in one male's hands.  Multiply that by $2$ because there are $2$ different possible males.  Figure out how many distributions put at least $4$ candies in both males' hands.  That takes care of the double-counting introduced in step $1$.

Comment: @RobertShore That's where I stopped, because if a boy gets at least 4 sweets, it means that he can get 4 or 5 or 6 and so on up to 16 and this complicates the counting of distributions

Comment: Are you required to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?  Could you count directly?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I've been told that the best way to do this is to use this principle, eventually I can somehow use stirling numbers of the second kind here but it's too complicated for me. Do you think it can be done more simply?

Comment: It could be done by considering cases, depending on how many candies each boy receives.  There are $16$ cases since you have $0 \leq a \leq 3, 0 \leq b \leq 3$, but some of them can be combined through symmetry arguments.  If the candies were indistinguishable, this would be a simple Inclusion-Exclusion problem.  Since the candies are all different, the problem is much more difficult for the reason you stated earlier in your response to Robert Shore.  That said, please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck in the question itself.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.   This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @KLS9 who says that the best way is principle of inclusion- exclusion ? It is very cumbersome by using it because of the candies are different..